# Idiomatic Typescript Enum Discriminated Union

Tags: typescript, enums, idioms, discriminated-union

As of typescript 2.0 you can use discriminated unions with an enum as the discriminant like this:

```
export function getInstance(code: Enum.Type1, someParam: OtherType1): MyReturnType1;
export function getInstance(code: Enum.Type2, someParam: OtherType2): MyReturnType2;
export function getInstance(code: Enum, someParam: UnionOfOtherTypes): UnionOfReturnTypes {
  switch (code) {
    case Enum.Type1:
      return new ReturnType1(someParam as OtherType1);
    case Enum.Type2:
      return new ReturnType2(someParam as OtherType2);
  }
}
```

**As of TypeScript 2.3**

- Is this the idiomatic way to do this?
- Are we able to infer the type of someParam without casting?
- Are we able to simplify the type definitions, maybe using generics, altering the function parameters, etc so we only need to define the final function?
- Is it possible declare the functions as consts like: `const getInstance = () => {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the idiomatic way to do this

No. if you need to use a type assertion e.g. `someParam as OtherType1` it is unsafe.

## More

- Unsafety of type assertion : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion
- The idiomatic way is to use discriminant properties instead of function overloading. Examples : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

Comment: I read your book all the time :) thank you!  Is it possible to infer the return type of some discriminated union based on a parameter? i.e. if code is type A i know the return type would be type B.

Comment: Yes. All return statements for a union for the return type. e.g. if you return a `string` and a `number` in different sections of your code the return type is inferred to be `string | number` 